# The weak topology on $H$ is the weak* topology on $H^*$ pulled back via $\Phi$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

I'm reading the following in Analysis Now by Pedersen:

The map, $H$ a Hilbert space
$$\Phi:H\to H^*: x\mapsto(\cdot\mid x)=[y\mapsto (y,x)]$$
is a conjugate linear isometry.

Then define the weak topology on $H$ as the topology induced by the family of functionals
$$\{x\mapsto(x,y)\mid y\in H\}=\{\Phi(y)\mid y\in H\}$$
Now Pedersen says the following:

> In follows that the weak topology on $H$ is the weak* topology on $H^*$ pulled back to $H$ via the map $\Phi$

but I don't quite understand what is meant by this. I would say this means that $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism between $H$ and $H^*$ both in their weak topologies.

But I don't quite see how this works. The weak* topology is induced by
$$\{[x\mapsto (x,y)]\mapsto(z,y)\mid z\in H\}=\{\Phi(y)\mapsto(z,y)\mid z\in H\}$$
And now I just don't see how to proceed from here.

I would appreciate someone shedding some light on this quote.

Comment: Is $H$ a Hilbert space? Then, the weak and the weak-* topologies on $H^*$ should coincide.

Comment: @gerw yes $H$ is a Hilbert space. Would you mind giving some more details, specifically giving a way to interpret and 'prove' the quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weak-* topology on $H^*$ is generated by the functionals
$$\{h^* \mapsto h^*(x) \mid x \in H\}$$
If you pull-back this topology to $H$, you get the topology generated by
$$\{y \mapsto \Phi(y)(x) \mid x \in H\} = \{y \mapsto (x,y) \mid x \in H\}$$
But this is the same as the weak topology which is generated by
$$\{y \mapsto (y,x) \mid x \in H\}$$

Comment: Thank you, I just figured it out myself too. For some reason the word pull back just didn't click in this context, but of course its just the actual pull back of the functionals from $H^*$ to $H$.